# need to create an array of vectors from a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vector

guys help i have a csv file that reads in fine but its a nested array of xyz positions how to i use this now to create an array of vector3 im using babylon.js

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
      var files = this.files;

      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        parseCSV(files[i], ',', function(result) {


          console.log(result); // THIS LOGS OUT AN ARRAY OF 1300 OBJECTS EACH ARRAY IS A NUMBER LIKE BELOW (0.01,0.05,0.04) ETC HOW DO I MAKE AN ARRAY like below using this data 

          var arraytest = [BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(),
            new BABYLON.Vector3(100, 20, 30),
            new BABYLON.Vector3(200, 160, 200),
            new BABYLON.Vector3(250, -210, 150),
            new BABYLON.Vector3(305, 300, 0)
          ];

          //SO BASICALLY I WANT TO CREATE THE ARRAY ABOVE^ BUT I WANNA USE the mega array above of my csv file so i can do the below and create a 3d spline arrays are my weakness bois

          var catmullRom = BABYLON.Curve3.CreateCatmullRomSpline(arr, 60);
          var catmullRomSpline = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateLines("catmullRom", catmullRom.getPoints(), scene);
          //console.log(result);

        });
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the CSV parses into an array like [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ...] you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to accomplish what you want, with the code

```
var arr = result.map(v => new BABYLON.Vector3(v[0], v[1], v[2]));
```

which essentially takes every element of the `result` array and replaces it with a new Vector using the 3 coordinates indicated by the array

Comment: Yea this kinda works but it does not render the spline getting an error i need to fire these 2 lines outside of the forloop or its going to create an issue -var catmullRom = BABYLON.Curve3.CreateCatmullRomSpline(arr,60);
  var catmullRomSpline = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateLines("catmullRom", catmullRom.getPoints(), scene);

but i cannot get this to work its cause the var is local to the for loop how do i make it global?

Comment: Outside of the for loop put the line `var arr;` then inside the for loop instead of doing `var arr = ...;` simply do `arr = ...` This will expand the scope of the variable to outside the for loop, which is much better practice than making it global.

Comment: hmm this does work but its giving me a cannot read property of 0 error on the romspline thing as if its null ? i assume this is an error to do with the window.load function? iv tried moving the var arr; to other areas of my code but this does not help babylon.js is bizzare not really sure the best practice here is this a dom issue?

Comment: does your debug console.log properly display an array structured the way I said in my answer?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Function.e.CreateCatmullRomSpline (babylon.js:1)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (main.js:143)
main.js:132 
["0", "0.01", "0"]
1: (3) ["0.002259989", "0.02", "0"]
2: (3) ["0.00452303", "0.03", "0"]
3: (3) ["0.00677539", "0.04", "0"]
4: (3) ["0.00900181", "0.05", "0"]
5: (3) ["0.011197713", "0.06", "0"]

and so and so on it splits every 100 arrays but i think this is a console log thing to keep it nice an coherent to read it.

Comment: I guess another thing you could do is log `arr` to make sure that it gets set properly

Comment: Also, maybe Babylon doesn't like strings, so you could try the code `arr = result.map(v => new BABYLON.Vector3(Number(v[0]), Number(v[1]), Number(v[2])));` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. hope this resolves your problem

```
var vectors = result.map((vector) => new BABYLON.Vector3(vector[0], vector[1], vector[2]));
var catmullRom = BABYLON.Curve3.CreateCatmullRomSpline([BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), ...vectors], 60);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i think this is a for loop issue its rendering the spline now but its all over the place its cause i have the lines of code in the for loop that makes the spline so its technically making the spline 1.3k times LOl but i cannot read the property of the data if i move these lines outside of the for loop as the scene is rendered first as i am waiting on the dom/window to load the file is there anyway to stop this i wanna run the scene then upload a csv file then it will generate a spline on the fly but it seems to be an issue with the ordering of the code that loads up i have posted the full thing below can anyone see a workaround for this ?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas"); // Get the canvas element 
    var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true); // Generate the BABYLON 3D engine

    /******* Add the create scene function ******/
    var createScene = function () {

        // Create the scene space
    var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
    scene.clearColor = new BABYLON.Color3( .5, .5, .5);

            // camera
    var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("camera1",  0, 0, 0, new 
    BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, -0), scene);
    camera.setPosition(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, -300));
    camera.attachControl(canvas, true);

    var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("light1", new BABYLON.Vector3(1, 0.5, 
    0), scene);
    light.intensity = 0.7;

    var spot = new BABYLON.SpotLight("spot", new BABYLON.Vector3(25, 15, -10), new 
    BABYLON.Vector3(-1, -0.8, 1), 15, 1, scene);
    spot.diffuse = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 1);
    spot.specular = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 0);
    spot.intensity = 0.8;

    var vectors;
    var catmullRom;
    var catmullRomSpline;


    var showAxis = function(size) {
    var makeTextPlane = function(text, color, size) {
    var dynamicTexture = new BABYLON.DynamicTexture("DynamicTexture", 50, scene, 
    true);
    dynamicTexture.hasAlpha = true;
    dynamicTexture.drawText(text, 5, 40, "bold 36px Arial", color , "transparent", 
    true);
    var plane = new BABYLON.Mesh.CreatePlane("TextPlane", size, scene, true);
    plane.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("TextPlaneMaterial", scene);
    plane.material.backFaceCulling = false;
    plane.material.specularColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 0);
    plane.material.diffuseTexture = dynamicTexture;
    return plane;
    };

    var axisX = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateLines("axisX", [ 
    new BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), new BABYLON.Vector3(size, 0, 0), new 
    BABYLON.Vector3(size * 0.95, 0.05 * size, 0), 
    new BABYLON.Vector3(size, 0, 0), new BABYLON.Vector3(size * 0.95, -0.05 * size, 
    0)
    ], scene);
    axisX.color = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 0);
    var xChar = makeTextPlane("X", "red", size / 10);
    xChar.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0.9 * size, -0.05 * size, 0);
    var axisY = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateLines("axisY", [
    new BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), new BABYLON.Vector3(0, size, 0), new BABYLON.Vector3( 
    -0.05 * size, size * 0.95, 0), 
    new BABYLON.Vector3(0, size, 0), new BABYLON.Vector3( 0.05 * size, size * 0.95, 
    0)
    ], scene);
    axisY.color = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 1, 0);
    var yChar = makeTextPlane("Y", "green", size / 10);
    yChar.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0.9 * size, -0.05 * size);
    var axisZ = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateLines("axisZ", [
    new BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, size), new BABYLON.Vector3( 
    0 , -0.05 * size, size * 0.95),
    new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, size), new BABYLON.Vector3( 0, 0.05 * size, size * 
    0.95)
    ], scene);
    axisZ.color = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 1);
    var zChar = makeTextPlane("Z", "blue", size / 10);
    zChar.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0.05 * size, 0.9 * size);
    };


    showAxis(50); 

    var advancedTexture = 
    BABYLON.GUI.AdvancedDynamicTexture.CreateFullscreenUI("UI");

    var button1 = BABYLON.GUI.Button.CreateSimpleButton("but1", "Test Button");
    button1.width = "150px"
    button1.height = "40px";
    button1.color = "white";
    button1.top = "-325px";
    button1.left = "-425px";
    button1.cornerRadius = 10;
    button1.background = "blue";
    button1.onPointerUpObservable.add(function() {
    camera.setPosition(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, -100));
    });
    advancedTexture.addControl(button1); 

    var button2 = BABYLON.GUI.Button.CreateSimpleButton("but1", "Origin");
    button2.width = "150px"
    button2.height = "40px";
    button2.color = "white";
    button2.top = "-275px";
    button2.left = "-425px";
    button2.cornerRadius = 10;
    button2.background = "green";
    button2.onPointerUpObservable.add(function() {
    camera.setPosition(new BABYLON.Vector3(35, 50, -300));


    });
    advancedTexture.addControl(button2); 


    function parseCSV(file, delimiter, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();


    reader.onload = function() {


    var lines = this.result.split('\n');

    var result = lines.map(function(line) {
    return line.split(delimiter);
    });


    callback(result);
    }

    reader.readAsText(file);
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', 
    function() {
    var files = this.files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    parseCSV(files[i], ',', function(result) {

    console.log(result);

        //arr = result.map(v => new BABYLON.Vector3(v[0], v[1], v[2]));

         vectors = result.map((vector) => new BABYLON.Vector3(vector[0], vector[1], 
         vector[2]));
         catmullRom = BABYLON.Curve3.CreateCatmullRomSpline([BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), 
         ...vectors], 60);

         catmullRomSpline = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateLines("catmullRom", 
         catmullRom.getPoints(), scene); 

         });    
         }

         })

         });           

         return scene;
         };    



         var scene = createScene(); //Call the createScene function


    // Register a render loop to repeatedly render the scene
    engine.runRenderLoop(function () { 
            scene.render();
    });

    // Watch for browser/canvas resize events
    window.addEventListener("resize", function () { 
            engine.resize();
    });
```